# how to use hough circles in cv2 with python?

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, hough-transform

I have the following code and I want to detect the circle.

```
   img = cv2.imread("act_circle.png")
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv2.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT)
```

it looks like it does not have the attribute and the error is the following

```
'module' object has no attribute 'CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT'
```

Does anybody know where this hidden parameters is?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT` belongs to the `cv` module, so you'll need to import that:

```
import cv2.cv as cv
```

and change your function call to

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT)
```

Now in current cv2 versions:

```
import cv2
cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT
```

Comment: or you can skip the import and just say `circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT)`

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I am using opencv 3.0.0 and it worked the following way:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray_im, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 10, np.array([]), 20, 60, m/10)[0]
```

i.e. instead of `cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT`, I have used just `cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT`.

Answer (score 5):

if you use OpenCV 3, then use this code :

```
img = cv2.imread("act_circle.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT) # change here
```